# ffmpeg 5.x and new channel layout syntax - getting warnings and errors with old syntax - cant find doc for new syntax

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

In ffmpeg 4.x this syntax worked for adding channel mapping to a 12 channel file (7.1.4):

```
ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "input_file.wav" -acodec pcm_s24le  -af "pan=7.1+TFL+TFR+TBL+TBR|FL=c0|FR=c1|FC=c2|LFE=c3|SL=c4|SR=c5|BL=c6|BR=c7|TFL=c8|TFR=c9|TBL=c10|TBR=c11" "out_12ch_mapped.wav"
```

Now in ffmpeg 5.x I get:

```
[Parsed_pan_0 @ 000002d6b99b7600] Channel layout '7.1+TFL+TFR+TBL+TBR' uses a deprecated syntax.
[Parsed_pan_0 @ 000002d6b99b7600] [SWR @ 000002d6b9d950c0] Input channel layout '12 channels' is not supported
[Parsed_pan_0 @ 000002d6b99b7600] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pan_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

and no amount of googling or reading the doc, or patches, reveals the new channel layout syntax or why "12 channels" is not supported.

Comment: No I have not found a solution